# Null check using Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to perform the null check in JDK8 using Optional utility. Here is my code I am writing which giving me an error:

```
java.util.Optional stringToUse = java.util.Optional.of(childPage.getContentResource().getValueMap().get("jcr:description").toString());
stringToUse.ifPresent(description = stringToUse);
```

Here "jcr:description" can be present or not. And if its present I want to use that value in description variable and if null the simply set blank String for description. Also can Lambda expression also can be use here? Thanks

Comment: Use `ofNullable` instead of `of`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the result of `get("jcr:description")` can be `null`, you shouldn’t invoke `toString()` on it, as there is nothing, `Optional` can do, if the operation before its use already failed with a `NullPointerException`.

What you want, can be achieved using:

```
Optional<String> stringToUse = Optional.ofNullable(
    childPage.getContentResource().getValueMap().get("jcr:description")
).map(Object::toString);
```

Then you may use it as

```
if(stringToUse.isPresent())
    description = stringToUse.get();
```

if “do nothing” is the intended action for the value not being present. Or you can specify a fallback value for that case:

```
description = stringToUse.orElse("");
```

then, `description` is always assigned, either with the string representation of `jcr:description` or with an empty string.

You can use `stringToUse.ifPresent(string -> description = string);`, if `description` is not a local variable, but a field. However, I don’t recommend it.

Comment: Could you please explain why you do not recommend it?